# Can't add TFS server: "Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.IssuedTokenCredential.set_TokenStorageUrl(System.Uri)'"

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

## Issue

I'm trying to connect to TFS 2018 in Visual Studio 2017.

When I click *Add*, this error pops up:

> Server '<server name>' was not added. Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.IssuedTokenCredential.set_TokenStorageUrl(System.Uri)'.

[image]

## Troubleshooting

So far, I have:

1. Run a repair (Visual Studio Installer)
2. Restarted
3. Uninstalled and reinstalled
4. Restarted
5. Run another repair

Comment: What version of TFS?

Comment: @DanielMann 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by reinstalling `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.dll` to the GAC.

#### Steps

1. Run *Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017* as administrator.
2. Enter these commands:

   ```
   cd %tmp%
   mkdir ms_vs_client
   cd ms_vs_client
   nuget install Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client
   cd Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client.15.131.1\lib\net45
   gacutil /i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.dll
   cd ..\..\..\..\
   rmdir ms_vs_client /s /q
   ```

#### Verification

If the DLL copied successfully, its date-modified timestamp should update. You can verify here:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common
```

Comment: if you miss nuget exe see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client/15.131.1 and/or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools how to fetch it